# JAXRS / CXF why is this simple post example not working

Tags: cxf, jax-rs

I know my client works as I post to another website and it all works.  I changed the client to post to url http://localhost:9000/enrollment/enroll and ran the following server...

```java
@Path("/enrollment")
public class MockHpsRestApi {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockHpsRestApi.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException, MuleException {
        log.info("starting the server");
        JAXRSServerFactoryBean sf = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
        sf.setResourceClasses(MockHpsRestApi.class);
        sf.setResourceProvider(MockHpsRestApi.class, new SingletonResourceProvider(new MockHpsRestApi()));

        sf.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:9000/");

        sf.create();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/enroll")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public String enrollment(MultipartBody body) throws IOException {
        log.info("received request="+body);
        Attachment att = body.getRootAttachment();
        ByteArrayOutputStream str = new ByteArrayOutputStream(100);
        InputStream in = att.getDataHandler().getInputStream();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(in, str);

            log.info("body payload received="+str);
            String xml = "success";
            return xml;
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(str);
        }
    }
}
```

My logs though say this when it receives the request...

```
2012-03-16 09:30:30,295 INFO 300 [main] c.i.e.s.i.MockHpsRestApi - starting the server 
Mar 16, 2012 9:30:30 AM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be http://0.0.0.0:9000/
2012-03-16 09:30:30,769 INFO 774 [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-7.5.4.v20111024 
2012-03-16 09:30:30,801 INFO 806 [main] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9000 STARTING 
2012-03-16 09:30:30,824 INFO 829 [main] o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler{,null} 
Mar 16, 2012 9:30:37 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils readFromMessageBody
WARNING: No message body reader has been found for request class MultipartBody, ContentType : application/xml.
Mar 16, 2012 9:30:37 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available
```

Why isn't this working?

hmmm, turning up the log levels, is this some kind of bug in CXF, though that would mean no one is really doing basic posts, so that doesn't seem right....(again, my client posts fine to another service today).

```
2012-03-16 09:51:01,414 DEBUG 10916 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Request path is: /enrollment/enroll 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,414 DEBUG 10916 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Request HTTP method is: POST 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,414 DEBUG 10916 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Request contentType is: application/xml 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,415 DEBUG 10917 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Accept contentType is: */* 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,415 DEBUG 10917 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.JAXRSInInterceptor - Found operation: enrollment 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,420 WARN 10922 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils - No message body reader has been found for request class MultipartBody, ContentType : application/xml. 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,423 WARN 10925 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper - WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available 
2012-03-16 09:51:01,428 DEBUG 10930 [qtp669588045-18 - /enrollment/enroll] o.a.c.j.i.WebApplicationExceptionMapper - no cause is available 
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1052) ~[cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:616) ~[cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:580) ~[cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:238) ~[cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:89) ~[cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263) [cxf-api-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123) [cxf-rt-core-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.serviceRequest(JettyHTTPDestination.java:323) [cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:289) [cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:72) [cxf-bundle-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:943) [jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:879) [jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117) [jetty-server-7.5.4.v20111024.jar:7.5.4.v20111024]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging the code, it turns out you can use the following types as parameters to the method above.

- `Source`
- `XMLSource`
- `Document`
- `byte[]`
- `InputStream`

I ended up using `InputStream`.

Comment: Let me comment on your code though. My personal opinion, but I think that - API-wise - it would be far better to return an HTTP code (like Reponse.Status.CREATED) rather than some incorrect xml ("success" is not a well-formed xml) sent as application/xml.

Comment: that was a prototype and while the input consumes xml, I am not sure the output was consumed at all...I think 200ok was enough and I just never removed that code.

Answer (score 1):

When using `@POST` and `@Consumes("application/xml")`, it's normal for the (single un-annotated) argument type on the method to be a JAXB-annotated class that CXF will deserialize the XML into before handing it to you. Is there a particular reason for not going that well-travelled route?

Comment: yes, performance, our system is fed xml and we feed xml to another system....just a passthrough and no reason to change to dom, jaxb or any of that stuff....it's way faster that way.